# Why does chrome throw 'getAttribute' is not a function error inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

With the following markup:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="one">one</div>
  <div id="two">two</div>
  <div id="three">three</div>
  <div id="four">four</div>
  <div id="five">five</div>
  <div id="six">six</div>
</div>

<p id="output">

</p>
```

and the following javascript:

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var items = document.querySelectorAll('#parent > div');

output.innerHTML += '#' + items[2].getAttribute('id') + '<br /><br />';

for(index in items){
        output.innerHTML += '#' + items[index].getAttribute('id') + ': ';
        output.innerHTML += items[index].innerHTML + '<br />';
}
```

Chrome throws the following error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: items[index].getAttribute is not a function

I have checked this in IE 11 and there are no errors in the console. What's weird is that the actual [result of the expression](https://jsfiddle.net/sxa1u1gy/3/) is correct.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var items = document.querySelectorAll('#parent > div');

output.innerHTML += '#' + items[2].getAttribute('id') + '<br /><br />';

for(index in items){
  output.innerHTML += '#' + items[index].getAttribute('id') + ': ';
  output.innerHTML += items[index].innerHTML + '<br />';
}
```

```css
#output{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="one">one</div>
  <div id="two">two</div>
  <div id="three">three</div>
  <div id="four">four</div>
  <div id="five">five</div>
  <div id="six">six</div>
</div>

<p id="output">

</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get id you need to do [DOMNode].id :

Working Snippet:

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var items = document.querySelectorAll('#parent > div');

output.innerHTML += '#' + items[2].id + '<br /><br />';

for (index in items) {
  output.innerHTML += '#' + items[index].id + ': ';
  output.innerHTML += items[index].innerHTML + '<br />';
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="one">one</div>
  <div id="two">two</div>
  <div id="three">three</div>
  <div id="four">four</div>
  <div id="five">five</div>
  <div id="six">six</div>
</div>

<p id="output">

</p>
```

**Update:**

The reason that there are `#undefined: undefined` being displayed in above snippet is that

> querySelectorAll() method returns all elements in the document that matches a specified CSS selector(s), as a static NodeList object

We need to use `length` property of this object to properly loop through all the matched elements.

Working snippet (Notice in console we can we two properties `length`, `item` . By for in  loop we traversed through these too but id and innerHTML are undefined ):

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var items = document.querySelectorAll('#parent > div');

output.innerHTML += '#' + items[2].id + '<br /><br />';

for (var index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
  output.innerHTML += '#' + items[index].id + ': ';
  output.innerHTML += items[index].innerHTML + '<br />';
}

console.log(items);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="one">one</div>
  <div id="two">two</div>
  <div id="three">three</div>
  <div id="four">four</div>
  <div id="five">five</div>
  <div id="six">six</div>
</div>

<p id="output">

</p>
```

Comment: All of the other answers seem to work but I like this one the best because it kind of explains why the original piece of code isn't working (ie. not accessing the property directly, hence 'is not a function')

Comment: Please explain why a *working* function report: `#undefined: undefined`?

Comment: @zer00ne : updated the answer with the reason and fixed code. Thanks for pointing the same :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for` loop instead. `for in` loops work better with key value pairs like object literals. Your *array-like* object does not have inherited enumerated properties.

> *A for...in loop only iterates over enumerable properties.*

from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');
var items = document.querySelectorAll('#parent > div');

output.innerHTML += '#' + items[2].getAttribute('id') + '<br /><br />';

for (let index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
  output.innerHTML += '#' + items[index].getAttribute('id') + ': ';
  output.innerHTML += items[index].innerHTML + '<br />';
}
```

```css
#output {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="one">one</div>
  <div id="two">two</div>
  <div id="three">three</div>
  <div id="four">four</div>
  <div id="five">five</div>
  <div id="six">six</div>
</div>

<p id="output">

</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

convert `var items` to this:

```
var items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#parent > div'));
```

`querySelectorAll` is not returning `array` but `NodeList` instead.

and because you work with IE also (which do not support Array.from).
It is better to check it first, something like this:

```
if (!Array.from) {
   //IE and else which do not support it
   var items = document.querySelectorAll('#parent > div');
} else {
   var items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#parent > div'));
}
```

[Array.from--Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `for...in` to iterate over arrays.

Use a regular for loop

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < items.length ; i++){
        output.innerHTML += '#' + items[i].getAttribute('id') + ': ';
        output.innerHTML += items[i].innerHTML + '<br />';
}
```